# How does AWS method level authorization know whether a user is a normal user or an administrator?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

[This tutorial](https://medium.com/aws-activate-startup-blog/api-security-for-modern-web-apps-a6a7f226a6d) explains how to setup two different IAM user types (`user` and `administrator`), in order to obtain a different set of gateway authorization credentials.

How is this setup within within Cognito (How do we assign the IAM user to the person logging in?) such that the the access credentials can be assigned for method level authorization?